# How to best fix wrong text height in Lazarus with High DPI?

Tags: windows, lazarus, dpi-aware

I have a bunch of TListBox components some of which define the `OnDrawItem` event in order to use colors (they also have `Style=lbOwnerDrawVariable`). My application is per-monitor DPI-aware (`<DpiAware Value="True/PM_V2"/>`). All my list boxes look fine unless I move my form to a monitor with a different DPI. Regular ListBoxes change their row height to accommodate a different font size, but ListBoxes with the `OnDrawItem` event fail to do so, resulting in text clipping if the DPI has increased, or a needlessly large row spacing if the DPI has decreased. For instance, here's what happens when going form 96 DPI to 120 DPI:

[image]

The bug persists until the content of a ListBox changes, new content is drawn with the correct row height.

My `OnDrawItem` handler for this list box looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ListDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  ARect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  ListBox: TListBox absolute Control;
  customColor: TColor;
begin
  customColor := clBlack;
  if Index = 1 then customColor := clBlue;

  ListBox.Canvas.FillRect(ARect);
  ListBox.Canvas.TextRect(ARect, ARect.Left, ARect.Top, ListBox.Items[Index]);
end;
```

I found a workaround which consists in manually updating the line height of my colorized ListBoxes:

```
procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
var
  ListHeight: Integer;
begin
  ListHeight := Canvas.GetTextHeight('|');
  ListBox1.ItemHeight := ListHeight;
  ListBox2.ItemHeight := ListHeight;
  //etc.
end;
```

However, this requires me to keep track of colorized ListBoxes, and in general it looks like a hack. Is there a way to fix this issue in Lazarus 2.2.6 without adding code for each new ListBox?